# Постепенный вывод всех перестановок через генератор

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7, перестановка

Необходимо с момощью генератора вывести все перестановки списка в виде строки, начиная с первого элемента и до их (неопределённого) полного количества. Пример:

```py
arr = ['1','2','3']
for perm in all_perms():
    print(perm)
```

Должно вывести:

```
1
2
3
11
12
13
14
21
22
23
24
31
32
33
34
41
42
43
44
123
(и так далее)
```

Пробовал со стандартными функциями в itertools, но проблема в том, что там сразу выводится список из кортежей, что не подходит, так как каждая перестановка должна быть обработана в цикле. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: В итертулс основные функции и есть генераторы. А даже если и список, то что мешает потом пройти по списку?..

Comment: Держать в памяти список из 100 и более эл-тов? Не вариант.

Comment: Это разве много? Сто миллионов это еще понимаю, а сто это вообще ни о чем.

Comment: На смартфоне бюджетного сегмента? На ПК без проблем, но скрипт для сматртфона.

Comment: Тем более 100 это до определения всех размещений.

Comment: @Евгений функции itertools - предельно ленивые. Не припомню ни одной, возвращающей список.

Comment: Да, только когда я обернул в свой генератор, он возвращал сразу всё.

Comment: @Евгений Не видя вашей программы, можно только гадать, но при правильном использовании генераторов так быть не должно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это не [перестановки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0), а [размещения с повторениями](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8).

```
import itertools

def f(seq):
    for n in range(1, len(seq) + 1):
        yield from itertools.product(seq, repeat=n)

for row in f('123'):
    print(''.join(row))
```

```
1
2
3
11
12
13
21
22
23
31
32
33
111
112
...
```